# give name to workbook vba

Tags: excel, vba

My question may be very simple for some. I want to add a workbook using VBA code and name is "AAA" or "AAA.xlsx". Can some one please help.

I tried :

```
Set outputWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

With outputWorkbook

    .Name = "AAA"
End With
```

or

```
Set outputWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

outputWorkbook.Name = "AAA"
```

They don't seem to be working. I get error as

> "Compile Error : Cant assign to read-only property"

Comment: You can't write to the `.Name`, it's a read-only property. Use `Workbook.SaveAs`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out as a possible solution

Set outputWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

outputWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "AAA"

Does this look right ?